# The Excel Hyperlink formula creates a hyperlink that does not open from Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Update: It works fine in Microsoft Online. It also works for other websites from the desktop version of Excel. I have contacted the iDox vendor.

I used a nested `Hyperlink(Concat())` formula in Excel 2016 to create a column that changes a dynamic URL based off of another column in my table. The URL is 238 characters, so the conversion does not generate an error. However, if I click the hyperlink in Excel, it takes me to the search page, not the search results, yet copying and pasting the URL into the browser or following the link from Google Sheets it works fine.

I also tried copying and pasting the results into text and converting to url again, but still could not open from Excel. Did I  skip a step that prevents Excel from properly opening the URL? Ideally, a solution will not use VBA or Macros.

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCAT("http://idox:8080/idox/searchresults.jsp?advanced=false&collectionId=2&libraryId=15&field_parcelnumber=&field_saledate=&field_buyername=&field_sellername=&field_property_street=&field_alternateid=&field_sdf_id=",[@[SDF ID]],"&search=Search"))
```

Comment: I could not reproduce it here, excel says it does not find the website.
But have you tried using & instead of CONCAT?
I don't know why, but I always prefer it.

Comment: there seems to be an problem with the domain name, I think it's an intranet domain?: "idox:8000"

Comment: You seem to have a lot of search parameters without search criteria e.g. `&field_property_street=`. Do you need all of those search parameters in the URL? Cutting down on those might help.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ed31df07-55af-41eb-b61a-82885a522703/hyperlinks-with-port-numbers-are-not-working-in-office-2010-products?forum=officeitproprevious